# Sorting strings before numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

For scoping purposes, I'm looking for an unusual sorting mechanism.
Let's suppose we have the following array:

```
arr = ["33", "a30", "b333", "44", "22", "a15"]
```

How can I sort it so that non-numeric strings sort before numeric ones?
This is the result I wish to achieve

```
sorted_arr = ["a15", "a30", "b333", "22", "33", "44"]
```

I have tried various combinations of `sort_by` and `sort` but I've not achieved the correct ordering yet... So, any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

PS: I know I've written "for scoping purposes", but the answer does not need to be for using in a `default_scope` block. I'll try to adjust it later, once I've found the right sorting technique.

Comment: Is it possible for a value have more than one alphabetic character? If so, is the array `["aa7", "b1"]` sorted in to suit your needs?

Comment: Yes, it can be any string @wicz

Comment: Why the `ruby-on-rails` tag?  Some, like me, often filter Rails questions.  It was only happenstance that I saw your question.  One should not omit relevant tags, but neither should one include superfluous ones.

Comment: @CarySwoveland have you read carefully? The main part is ruby, but it has a rails projection.

Comment: Ruby, I'm afraid I don't know enough about Rails to know what a "Rails projection" is. :-) Perhaps my comment was naive, but I noticed all the answers are pure Ruby.  My point, though, is that if any tag is not essential, you may unnecessarily miss out on good answers..

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for the point. What I mean is I was planning to take the answer to a default_scope, which is Railsie, not requesting the answers to go that way though. I think I express it quite clear in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
arr.sort_by{|e| [e =~ /\A\d/ ? 1 : 0, e.your_original_sort_condition]}
```

Comment: Sorry, what would be `my_original_sort_condition`?

Comment: Since any string can be used, only full numerals must match, hence I'll use : `arr.sort_by{|e| [e =~ /\A\d+\z/ ? 1 : 0, e]}`

Comment: If `"0a"` were regarded as a "non-numeric string", perhaps `e.strip =~ /\D/ ? 0 : 1`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it.

**Code**

```
def sort_em(arr)
  a = arr.sort
  return a if a.first =~ /\D/ || a.last !~ /\D/  
  a.rotate(a.index(a.find { |e| e =~ /\D/ }))
end
```

**Example**

```
arr = ["33", "a30", "b333", "44", "22", "a15"]
sort_em(arr)
  #=> ["a15", "a30", "b333", "22", "33", "44"]
```

**Notes**

- This will not work if, before separating the numeric and non-numeric entries, you perform some specialized `sort` that intermixes numeric and non-numeric entries.
- If `" 1"` or `"1 "` may be present and are to be treated as "numeric", add `.strip` before `=~` and `~=~`.
- If `arr` is empty, `[].first =~ /^\d+$/ #=> nil`

**Gentlemen, start your engines**

```
require 'benchmark'

n = 10 # Example
arr = (Array.new(n) {rand(n).to_s } +
       Array.new(n) { (97+rand(26)).chr + rand(n).to_s }).shuffle
  #=> ["9", "5", "a4", "u6", "u3", "g6", "5", "l0", "9", "9",
  #    "3", "8", "t1", "3", "o5", "l6", "3", "i6", "l1", "0"]

n = 200_000
arr = (Array.new(n) {rand(n).to_s } +
       Array.new(n) { (97+rand(26)).chr + rand(n).to_s }).shuffle

def sawa(arr)  arr.sort_by{ |e| [e =~ /\A\d/ ? 1 : 0, e] } end
def darse(arr) arr.partition { |x| x =~ /\D/ }.flat_map(&:sort) end    
def uri(arr)   arr.sort.partition { |x| x[/^[^\d]/] }.inject(:+) end
def cary(arr)
  a = arr.sort
  return a if a.first =~ /\D/ || a.last !~ /\D/  
  a.rotate(a.index(a.find { |e| e =~ /\D/ }))
end

Benchmark.bm(12) do |bm|
  bm.report('@sawa'     ) { sawa(arr)  }
  bm.report('@theDarse' ) { darse(arr) }
  bm.report('@UriAgassi') { uri(arr)   }
  bm.report('@Cary'     ) { cary(arr)  }
end
                   user     system      total        real
@sawa          3.340000   0.020000   3.360000 (  3.364740)
@theDarse      0.530000   0.020000   0.550000 (  0.547846)
@UriAgassi     0.700000   0.010000   0.710000 (  0.711513)
@Cary          0.430000   0.010000   0.440000 (  0.438975)
```

Admittedly, it's a very limited benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most elegant solution but one way to do this would be to create two arrays, one holding all the elements starting with a non-numeric, one holding all the elements starting with a numeric item.  Sort the two arrays and then concatenate the arrays

Comment: I suggest `def strange_sort(arr) arr.partition { |x| x =~ /\D/ }.flat_map(&:sort) end`.  I expected that to be fastest in my benchmark, because I thought that sorting two arrays of sizes `n` and `m` would be faster than sorting one array of size `n+m`.  It did very well, but had to settle for silver. That may just reflect the limited benchmark, of course.  I would have `+1`'d your answer if you had provided code.

Comment: I didn't provide code because i Don't know Ruby- Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
arr.sort.partition { |x| x[/^[^\d]/] }.inject(:+)
#  => ["a15", "a30", "b333", "22", "33", "44"]
```

This sorts the array, then it groups all the elements not starting with a digit, and all the elements that do:

```
arr.sort.partition { |x| x[/^[^\d]/] }
# => [["a15", "a30", "b333"], ["22", "33", "44"]]
```

and then it joins the two arrays together.

Comment: Thanks, I've thought about splitting too, but it's not useful for scopes

Comment: @RubyRacer what do you mean by 'not useful for scopes'?

Comment: Can I use split array in default_scope block?

Comment: @RubyRacer if I understand your question, you are asking about working within the [query interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html). If that's the case - [`sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) is also not supported by the query interface, so that won't work either. You want a solution using [`order`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order). I'm afraid, though, that such a solution will have to be SQL specific, and might change according to which database you are using...

Comment: I was planning to try the conversion and if it doesn't work I'll take the ordering to the controller.